# Why is my Node.js getting "program terminated" without an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a fairly large Node.js project that's been working great for an extensive period of development. Recently however -- and unfortunately cannot pinpoint exactly when it changed -- my application has started exiting with `program terminated` **only when running from within the node.js debugger**.

**The big question: How do I find out what is causing this error?**

**Breakdown of what I know**:

- Only seems to occur from within the debugger (e.g. `node debug main.js`)
- Same results with Node 4.2.5 & 4.2.6. With Node 5.5.0, the debugger generally just stops working when this happens.
- There is **no additional output** such as stack trace or error messages, only "program terminated"
- process events of `SIGINT`, `exit`, nor `uncaughtException` are hit
- Through `console.log()` I've been able to determine that this happens when I `require` a module (more information on this below)
- The `require` logic is surrounded by `try`/`catch` but it does not catch
- I have tried using a `domain`'s `error` handler to catch this by putting the `require` portion in the `run` method but nothing caught there, either
- I've used tools such as [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) to ensure I do not have any circular dependencies (Perhaps there is a better way to do this)

**About require**:

My program has a "plugin" type system in which modules are `require`'d at runtime as needed. The offending `require` is not deterministic from what I can tell, however: A module that can be `require`'d a few times in a row with success fails other times.

Again, this is code that has been working for months. I've been making some fairly extensive changes (but not to the area of code using `require` mentioned above) when I started noticing this. Since I can often run for a few minutes without issue though many different code paths before seeing this, it's hard to say what is triggering this.

What else can I do here?!

For reference, the (not quite up to date as I've not pushed my changes) code [is on Github](http://github.com/NuSkooler/enigma-bbs/), if that helps.

Comment: Seriously, how is this possibly off topic / down voted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot more digging and asking around I have some answers, so I'll answer this myself:

- As for the particular error, it seems to be a Node.js bug
- As for the question of "Why am I getting this error?" read on...

**The Cause**

When Node.js itself encounters a segfault, the program (e.g. .js) will simply stop. **You will not get an exception, error handlers executed, etc**. as the underlying `node` has died. If you're running under the debugger, the only message you'll see is `program terminated`.

**Finding Out Why**

To find out why `node` is terminating a couple options work well:

1. Install [node-segfault-handler](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler).
2. Use `gdb`

**node-segfault-handler**

`node-segfault-handler` is a drop in module that will give you a basic call stack when something explodes. Simply `require` and init it at the top of your `index.js` or equivalent:

```
var SegfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');
SegfaultHandler.registerHandler("crash.log");
```

See the [authors page](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler) for additional information and usage.

**gdb**

With `gdb` you can get more readable stack information and truly debug if needed. Note that a common cause for Node.js segmentation faults is native module(s) you may be using. If this is the case, it's probably a good idea to (re)build them with debug symbols so your stack trace has something useful. Native modules are generally using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). In this case, find the modules `binding.gyp` file's `cflags` member and add `-g` to it. Example from the [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) package:

```
 "cflags": [ "-include ../src/gcc-preinclude.h", "-g" ],
```

Next rebuild the module(s) you updated:

```
npm rebuild --build-from-source sqlite3
```

Finally, execute `node` and your program under `gdb` or attach it. To debug the debugger (like in my case) the steps would be something like this:

1. In the shell, run your node app with `gdb --args` in front, e.g. `gdb --args node debug main.js`
2. At the gdb prompt, enter `run`
3. Wait for the crash. Once you hit it, type `bt` to get the stack information, or debug away!

Comment: I had the same issue with node 4.3.0 version then I install node^6.2.0 version and it solved the issue.

Comment: Note that you can debug with gdb from a single shell. Using your example, `gdb --args node debug main.js` will start gdb. At the gdb prompt you can enter `run` to run the node.js app, then `bt` after the crash. (Update: added to answer).